# what is the ingredient that makes my takeout lo mein smoky tasting?

Tags: flavor

Have a great place for Chinese takeout.  Love their Lo Mein.  It has a great smoky taste.  Alas when reheating left overs, the smoky taste is gone.  Would like to replace/add to the Lo Mein, but not sure what the seasoning is.  Can it be toasted sesame or something else.  It really is a great enhancement to the dish.  When asked, the Chinese restaurant said they make their own Lo Mein sauce...no help to me.

Answer (score 10):

If I'm understanding your question right, you might be referring to "wok hei," or the "breath of the wok." It's the flavor that restaurant food has because of the high heat of the woks in a professional cooking environment, and home stoves have a very hard time reproducing it. I found it covered in another Cooking Stack Exchange here:

[What Is Wok Hai And How Do I Get It In My Food?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/5157/what-is-wok-hai-and-how-do-i-get-it-in-my-food)

Answer (score 4):

I've seen Chinese restaurants where they cook over an open flame - if yours does the same, the smoky flavor might be from actual smoke, lightly perfuming the food.  It can be quite appealing, but if it's an aroma from the restaurant rather than one in the dish, that would explain why it didn't last long enough to be reheated.

There's no easy way to recreate that smoky atmosphere at home without smoke alarms going off, but you might try adding the flavor in other ways - some of the [liquid smoke](http://www.wisegeek.org/what-is-liquid-smoke.htm) seasoning (usually used to give smoky flavors to meat without the technical difficulty of smoking), which can be tricky to use until you figure out how much you need to get the effect you want.  Or smoked salt, which would obviously add salt to the dish.

You might be able to add the smoky flavor to something you wouldn't mind adding to your dish, if you don't want to add extra salt - maybe add a drop of liquid smoke to toasted sesame as you suggest, or find something else altogether... I saw a recipe for [smoked egg yolk bottarga](http://www.tastingtable.com/cook/national/smoked-egg-bottarga-jonathan-sawyer-greenhouse-tavern-cleveland), for example.

Comment: Just a drop of *liquid smoke.* I can't overstate how important the *drop* part is. I once ruined a dish by going too far with LS. It's like salt: once you have added too much, it's pretty much game over. I had a recipe for 3 gallons of BBQ sauce, it used 3 tbsp of LS.

Answer (score 1):

This video claims it is the mushroom flavored dark soy sauce that causes the "smoky" flavor.  I also have been searching the "way" Chinese restaurants and buffets create that smoky flavor I don't get at home.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4Qtmz1FDww0

Answer (score 0):

I use black rice vinegar and it isn’t that at all. I’ve noticed it consistently in the large flat noodle dish, i think it is called Beef or Chicken Chow Fun (Foon). it is Cantonese and HK dish. they say in wiki that the flavour is obtained by “searing” the beef, but ai don’t believe this; I believe the flavour is a sauce, sn additive because I remember many years ago—30-40 years ago,I worked in a Chinese Schizuan restaurant and the cook made some mention of it. In addition, if anyone with a wok and oil could produce this on a high flame, there would be thousands of chefs who would be doing it on tv, and in cook books, etc. I just saw someone wrote “liquid smoke” snd that is what it is that gives chow foon a smoky taste.

Comment: Perhaps the sauce the chef mentioned was made from ingredients that had "Wok Hei"? If that's the case, I too would really love to know! To be honest though, I don't think there's any way of getting the Wok Hei taste without a very powerful gas burner like the ones used in restaurants. They're 10x more powerful than standard home burners (in BTU ratings).

As for liquid smoke, I don't think it's the answer as (in my experience), it's always wood flavoured smoke. Which is great for BBQ style flavours but it's not the same as the Wok Hei taste.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/90966)

Answer (score -1):

They might use Chinkiang black rice vinegar

Comment: Can you explain a bit? What is that vinegar and why does it add smoky flavor? Maybe replace the brand name with something generic?

Comment: @Robert It's not a brand name, it's a specific vinegar. It does have plenty of flavor but I'm not sure it's smoky, though.